# Will Facebook charge me to create an app?

Tags: facebook

I'm wish to use Facebook authentication for my website. Facebook says I require an appId. When I want to create an app, it asks for my credit card details. Will they charge me to just to get an appId?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No.** You get the app id when you register it at facebook for free.

Here: http://developers.facebook.com/setup/